# How to use the psql command to list, create, use and examine databases?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm a postgreSQL newbie and I can't find any usable introduction to using the psql command. At least I think that's the command I want to use.

Is it possible in postgreSQL to simply connect to the server and then list, create, use and examine databases?

I'd like to be able to use psql to do something like this with MySQL (I've deleted many extra lines):

Connect without specifying a database - I can't seem to do that with psql:

```
$ mysql -u root -prootpassword
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Server version: 5.5.28 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

I can list databases with mysql but the posgreSQL command SHOW doesn't seem to do it.

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| ocdp               |
| performance_schema |
| test               |
+--------------------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

I can switch databases.

```
mysql> use ocdp;
Database changed
```

I can't figure out this command in psql:

```
mysql> show tables;
+---------------------------------+
| Tables_in_ocdp                  |
+---------------------------------+
| OCAddresses                     |
| OCStreets                       |
+---------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I think I can do this in psql with 'createdb' and 'dropdb' commands:

```
mysql> create database foo;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> drop database foo;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.03 sec)
```

I use \quit

```
mysql> quit
Bye
```

The answer to these questions should take only a moment for someone who knows postgreSQL but I just can't find documentation anywhere that shows how to do these simple operations.  Maybe I shouldn't even be using psql at all for this?

Comment: [man psql](http://linux.die.net/man/1/psql) [Pg official docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

connect to server:

```
$ mysql -u root -prootpassword

$ su - postgres
$ psql
```

list databases:

```
mysql> show databases;

postgres=# \l
```

switch databases:

```
mysql> use ocdp;

postgres=# \c ocdp
```

show tables:

```
mysql> show tables;

postgres=# \dt
```

create database:

```
mysql> create database foo;

postgres=# create database foo;
```

drop database:

```
mysql> drop database foo;

postgres=# drop database foo;
```

quit:

```
mysql> quit

postgres=# \q
```

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use `su` when starting psql. You can easily specify the user you want to use to connect as a parameter to psql.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : That's true. But sometimes (often?) one has a 'postgres' user that has special environmental settings (PATH, locale) that make easier to invoke psql.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: on first use, if you don't su to postgres, you can't do anything. Because when you've just installed postgres, there's no user account other than postgres to connect with, and you can't do `psql -U postgres` from a random user acccount, thanks to `pg_hba.conf`. `su postgres` or `sudo su postgres` is good advice for a beginner who also happens to the administrator of the machine.

Answer (score 3):

Try Using this command if you are using Mac-OS-X and for postgres 9.4

psql --list

Answer (score 2):

#### *Connect without specifying a database - I can't seem to do that with psql:*

Quote [from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> *The default user name is your Unix user name, as is the default database name*

---

#### *I can switch databases*

Quote [from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> *\connect [ dbname [ username ] [ host ] [ port ] ] Establishes a new connection to a PostgreSQL server*

---

#### *show tables*

Quote [from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> *\d[S+] [ pattern ]
>       For each relation (table, view, index, sequence, or foreign table) or composite type matching the pattern, show all columns*

---

#### *create database foo;*

This is the same statement in PostgreSQL, which is [documented in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html)

---

#### *quit*

Quote [from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html)

> *\q or \quit Quits the psql program.*

Comment: I tried to check both sets of answers, but I guess that's a no-no in our hyperindividualistic society.

Comment: I tried to check both sets of answers, but I guess that's a no-no in our hyperindividualistic society.  This has helped me a lot.  I'm going to go run thru the steps a couple of times to see if I can internalize this and figure out a bit about the notion of users (I know I'm now supposed to say 'roles'). Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Postgresql with terminal

enter into the postgresql

```
   sudo -u postgres psql
```

find list Of databases in postgresql by

```
   $ \l
```

connect to database by following command

```
   $ \c databasename
```

view models in database by

```
   $ \dt
```

Now list of table present in database are displayed and perform operations on the tables like

```
   $ select * from table;
```